# Already used one ng-view, should I use ng-include now?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view, angularjs-ng-include

I am creating a SPA using Angular 1.

- User will have a login template to access the portal.
- Now on this portal, user will be able to perform CRUD operations.

for switching templates during CRUD operations, I'm already using `ng-view` in particular div.
Now I'm confused what should I use to switch template inside `<body>` with login, register and portal template. One options is `ng-include`.

Please share a better approach if you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used nested and multiple views using `ui-router`, worked like charm.